# SAPUI5 table border color/width

Tags: javascript, css, sapui5

I have a simple table (sap.m.Table) in my popover.

```
<Table headerText="Table 1">

            <columns>
                <Column mergeDuplicates="true">
                    <header>MyData</header>
                </Column>
            </columns>

            <ColumnListItem>
                 <VBox alignItems="End">
                    <Text text="{i18n>myOwnField}: Data1"/>
                 </VBox>
            </ColumnListItem>

</Table>
```

[image]

I want to remove the borderline of the table. According to our requirement, I cannot use custom CSS to do this. I need to use inbuilt methods provided by UI5 framework.

However, [SAPUI5 guideline](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Table) does not provide any property named *border width*.

I found **sapUiListTableFixedBorderColor** property on [theme parameter toolbox](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/m/demokit/theming/webapp/index.html), but not sure how can I use this in my current coding, or will it be useful at all.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions/tips.

Comment: Having both requirements : 'no custom css' and 'custom styles' sounds weird. I do not know who gives you requirements but you should definitly challenge those :p

Comment: Does the table contain only a single column all the time? How did you manage to display `MyData` without a control in the `<header>` aggregation? The sample code you provided doesn't seem to correspond to the code in the screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sap.m.ListBase` (from which your Table derives) has a property `showSeparators`.

It expects the following values: `All` (default), `Inner`, `None`.

With `None` a table will look like this:

[image]

With `Inner` it will look like this:

[image]

With `All` it will look like this:

[image]

---

**Note:**

This will not affect the thick line between the `headerText` and the column texts. If you don't want that line, do not use the headerText property but build your own title (`sap.m.Title`).

The thick line between the column texts and the first table line will become noticeably thinner if you use `Inner` or `None`. But it will not vanish completely.

Hope that helps.